# Control Flow of if statement and function calls

Tags: c, if-statement, recursion, function-calls

I am getting the output ' 0,1,2,0'. Please someone help me how this function call is working. I have this doubt that after decrementing n, if statement will not execute as it will not be greater than 0. Thus there will be no output. But the result is something else.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int);

int main(void)
{
    int a=3;
    fun(a);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int n)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        fun(--n);
        printf("%d,", n);
        fun(--n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get a piece of paper and write out the call sequence. Given that `a` is small, it'll be easy.

Comment: write a few more `printf` statements. ex: before `if` block write one more statement to know the value of `n` initially in that call.

Comment: No disrespect meant but do you know what recursion is? If not, you might want to read up on it for instance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science) . If you do know, please add that you do know what recursion is to your question so we know to focus on other aspects of the question.

Comment: The `fun(--n)` prints its value before your `fun(a)`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `fun()` from within itself, both *before* and *after* the `printf()`.  So you're going to see the `printf` from the *deepest* invocation of `fun()` *first*.

@ForceBru is absolutely right, you can - and, if you want to be a programmer, *need* to be able to - trace the code out in your head or on paper.  Here's an example.

on the first invocation of `fun()`, as is 3.  3 > 0 so `fun()` is called again, with the _pre_decremented value ( so `n` is set to 2, and 2 is passed to `fun()`.

The whole process happens again.  2 > 0 so `--n` or 1 is passed to `fun`.

In the 3rd invocation deep, `n` is 1.  That's still greater than 0, so `fun(--n)` is run again, with n being predecremented to 0.

Now within the fourth invocation of `fun()`, n is finally 0.  Nothing happens.

Third invocation, first `fun()` returns.  Rember, this `fun()` invocation's `n` was 1, but it's been decremented to 0 by this time.  0 is printed. `n` is then decremented again ( to -1, it being a signed int) and `fun(-1)` is called, but since `-1 > 0` is false, nothing happens.  The third invocation returns.

The second invocation was passed 2 but has since decremented to 1.  1 is printed and then `fun(--n)` turns into `fun(0)` and the next `fun() invcocation is`fun(-1)`and also does nothing.  The second invocation of`fun()` returns.

Finally, the first invocation of `fun()`, the one from main, is executing agian.  It started with 3, but decremented to 2.  A 2 is printed.  Then `--n`, or 1, is passed to `fun()` one last time.  `1>0` so `fun() is invoked again, and outputs`--1`or 0 just like it did the first time it was passed a 1.    The first invocation's recursive calls to`fun()`then finish, and the program finishes, having output a`0, 1, 2, 0`.

Do walk through that yourself on paper, as recursive functions can be pretty confusing.  I didn't understand why you got that output myself until I walked through the code, and I've been programing in c for 20 years!